# How can I retrieve programmatically all the available IL instructions of the .NET CLR?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, il

It is possible to get programmatically the list of all the IL instructions that a .NET compiler can produce?

Comment: You can try [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions) first.

Answer (score 2):

They are all available on the [System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 1):

The IL instructions are defined in the ECMA-335 - Common Language Infrastucture standard document (Opcode encodings - pag. 295).

The document is publicly available and can be downloaded from the following link:

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

However, the opcodes are define also in the class System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes, that is part of the mscorlib.dll types.
Below the code that can be used to extract the relevant information from that class:

```
// Get the OpcCodes using Reflection
Type opCodes = typeof(OpCodes);
var opCodesList = opCodes.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
.Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(OpCode))
.Select(f => 
{   OpCode opCode = (OpCode)f.GetValue(null);
    return new {Name=f.Name, Instruction = opCode.Name, Size = opCode.Size, OpCode = string.Format("0x{0:X2}", opCode.Value) };
});

// Print to the Console
var opCodesStrings = opCodesList
.Select( o => string.Format("{0,-10}{1,-15}{2,-10}{3,-10}", o.Name, o.Instruction, o.Size, o.OpCode))
.ToList();
opCodesStrings.Insert(0, string.Format("{0,-10}{1,-15}{2,-10}{3,-10}", "Name", "Instruction", "Size", "OpCode"));
opCodesStrings.Insert(1, string.Format("{0,-10}{1,-15}{2,-10}{3,-10}", "----", "-----------", "----", "------"));
opCodesStrings.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

The first lines of the produced output are:

```
   

    Name      Instruction    Size      OpCode    
    ----      -----------    ----      ------    
    Nop       nop            1         0x00      
    Break     break          1         0x01      
    Ldarg_0   ldarg.0        1         0x02      
    Ldarg_1   ldarg.1        1         0x03      
    Ldarg_2   ldarg.2        1         0x04      
    Ldarg_3   ldarg.3        1         0x05      
    Ldloc_0   ldloc.0        1         0x06      
    Ldloc_1   ldloc.1        1         0x07      
    Ldloc_2   ldloc.2        1         0x08      
    Ldloc_3   ldloc.3        1         0x09      
    Stloc_0   stloc.0        1         0x0A      
    Stloc_1   stloc.1        1         0x0B      
    Stloc_2   stloc.2        1         0x0C      
    Stloc_3   stloc.3        1         0x0D      
    Ldarg_S   ldarg.s        1         0x0E      
    Ldarga_S  ldarga.s       1         0x0F      
    ...
```

The following link points to the MSDN page describing each OpCode:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/System.Reflection.Emit.OpCodes(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: If you want to get them from the OpCodes class, then you would need to filter out the 'Prefix[1-7]' op codes as they do not relate to real op codes. Also, OpCodes does not include the "no." prefix op code, so you would need to include it manually.